# Draw horizontal line according to value entered in userform (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I want my command button to draw a horizontal line, on an existing chart, such that it is equal to the value entered in that same userform.

A similar question was asked before, so I got inspired by their answers to code. But it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim d As Double
    d = res
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil3").ChartObjects("Graphique 2").Chart 
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = Array(d, d)
            .ChartType = xlLine
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Where `res` is that value that the user enters.

Here is my result (it seems like it draws a line at 0, not at the `res` value; It also shifts all my x axis to the right).

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I'd use this method [Add a Horizontal Line to a Column or Line Chart: Error Bar Method](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineHorzErrBar.html).  You then just have to transfer the value from the _Userform_ to a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ActiveChart` from your second `With` line - you never activated a chart, so it's hard to know which chart is receiving that new series. This code worked fine for me:

It's hard to tell what you were trying to do, but it looks like you only wanted 2 data points. It'd be best to add something dynamic to this to figure out how many data points you need, then create the array to assign to `.Values`.

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim d As Double
    d = 5 'just assigning it here
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart 
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = Array(d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d) '10 data points
            .ChartType = xlLine
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: img1]

**Edit:**

```
Sub Test3()
Dim d As Double
Dim numberofpoints As Long, i As Long
Dim arr As Variant

d = 5 'just assigning it here
numberofpoints = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
ReDim arr(0 To 0)

For i = 0 To numberofpoints - 1
    arr(i) = d
    If i <> numberofpoints - 1 Then ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i + 1)
Next i

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = arr
        .ChartType = xlLine
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

[image: img2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works better now, but with the 10 points (of the array), it's only a tiny point. I need much more. Do you have an idea how to do that, not manually?

Comment: @Narjems It'd be easiest to get the number from where your original date series is stored - could you give me an example of how/where you store it?

Comment: I modified it such that both the date and price columns are next to the chart.

Comment: I tried adding  `Dim e, f As Date
e = DateSerial(1998, 3, 27)
f = DateSerial(2018, 3, 27)                                                               .XValues = Array(e, f) `  . But not working

Comment: I've edited my post with an example of how we get our number of data points from the original data, then use that to build the array for the straight line series.